# How to make particles collide on face instead of median point?

Tags: particles, collision

I made a scene where particles collide with a plane, but the particles seem to collide on their median point:

[image]

i want it to collide with their faces, so their faces don't go through the plane... is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Enable "*Size deflect*" in the "*Physics*" tab of the particle system

[image]

Result with randomly rotated Suzannes:

[image]

Comment: the mesh stil goes through the plane... maybe because i use dynamic rotation?

Comment: You're right: I can see that dynamic rotation and size deflect have some weird interplay. I'm afraid I don't know how to make they work as you expect. That being said, I believe that if you don't have too many particles, actually converting them to mesh and tweaking with Rigid Body parameters gives you more control over collisions